# SignUp JS jQuery on Parse.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, parse-platform

What's wrong with this code? I almost sure that something's wrong with the form's submitting: not getting any of alerts and users are not being created, but can not understand where I made a mistake... APP ID and JS ID cleared for secrecy :)

HTML code has a form and the submit button, form has an ID = registration, button's id = registerForm

Tried to find this problem on the internet and found many variations of submitting the form, but neither helped :(

```
 Parse.initialize("", "");

var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
if(curentUser) {
    alert("Already logged in");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registerForm').click(function(){
$('#registration').submit(function() {

    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

        //validation
        var errors = "";
        if(username === "") errors += "Username required.<br/>";
        if(password === "") errors += "Password required.<br/>";
        if(email === "") errors += "Email required.<br/>";

        if(errors !== "") {
            alert("Error!")
            return;
        }

    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", username);
    user.set("password", password);
    user.set("email", email);

    user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
            alert("Yay!");
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you seeing username, passwrod values coming through?

Comment: I think not. Tried to add this element to code but didn't get an alert: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerForm").click(function(){
        value = $("#username").attr('value'); 
        alert(value);
    });
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And finally it worked with the code from a neighbor thread: [parse.com & java script- upload image for user and show the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210948/parse-com-java-script-upload-image-for-user-and-show-the-image?rq=1)

I'm sorry to its author, I accidentally used your parse.initialize ID's, feel free to delete that fancy Tom Hardy with my email :D

Code that worked for me (and I changed in my html-code `<button></button>` to `<input type="submit">`) :

```
Parse.initialize("blabla", "blablatwo");

$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("submit", "#registration", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  var username = document.getElementById('username').value;     
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

  var user = new Parse.User();
  user.set("username", username);
  user.set("email", email);
  user.set("password", password);

  var fileUploadControl = $("#profilephoto")[0];

  if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
    var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
    var name = "photo.png";
    var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
    parseFile.save().then(function(parseFile) {
      var url = parseFile.url();
      user.set("image", url);
      user.signUp();
      }, 
      function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      });
  };
});
});
```